# Web API Model Validation - Error Message is empty

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm using standard model validation attributes (e.g. Required) as a first line of defense against invalid model, later on I have additional checks that can not be done by using standard model validation attributes.

I have one ActionFilterAttribute where I check for model state, null model properties and so on..

What is strange here is the following

in method OnActionExecuting we have HttpActionContext and there is ModelState property which has property IsValid indicating if model is valid or not (excluding cases when property of model is null, but that I cover later on...).

So, when the model is not valid, than actionContext.ModelState.First().Value.Errors (collection of ModelError) contains all model validation errors. So, ModelError contains ErrorMessage and Exception attributes, and when I check for each of them, ErrorMessage is not initialized but Exception property is initialized and contains details of validation failure. Further more, ModelError class has 3 constructors:

```
public ModelError(Exception exception);
public ModelError(string errorMessage);
public ModelError(Exception exception, string errorMessage);
```

So it seems that for some reason the first one is called by framework, instead of the last one.

Any ideas why this happens? What can I do in order to get ErrorMessage Initialized?

Regards,
Novak